# Buffalo with DD-WRT not applying static ip address

Tags: windows, static-ip, buffalo-router

Not sure what's going on here. I have a Buffalo that came with DD-WRT v24SP2-MULTI(04/12/11)_std firmware.

I go into Services tab and under Static Leases set a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine's MAC address to a static IP, but it's not working. I set the static IP to 192.168.1.3 but this setting is ignored and the machine is given an IP address by DHCP, which results in random addresses like 192.168.1.57 or so.

So then I set Static IPv4 address on the machine itself. This works... mostly, except sometimes for some reason the machine likes to change its supposedly static IP address to something completely out of the subnet that is like 169.254.130.192

Very very weird, I haven't got a clue what's going on. I've never had this happened to me before.

Comment: The 169.254.0.0/16 IPv4 address indicates DHCP error. http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/

Comment: I see. Can you help solve why my Static Lease is not working? Thanks

Comment: "When a host fails to dynamically acquire an address, it can optionally assign itself a link-local IPv4 address in accordance with RFC 3927" But I am trying to NOT do that. I don't want my machine to try dynamically acquire an address. I want the router to set it to a static IP.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my answer?  Router's don't normally set static IP's...they're set on the machines themselves.

Comment: I tried it. Deleted static lease entry from router. Will observe for a few hours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To set a static IP in Server 2008, follow the instructions on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754203%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

The 169.254.0.0/16 IPv4 address indicates [DHCP error](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained).

You should not have to set up the static IP on the router itself.  Make sure that the IP address you are assigning your server is not in the DHCP range.

Comment: trying this solution. will report in a few hours.